# space between date and time using date_i18n function in php/wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, internationalization

I am working on a php code as shown below :

`<?php echo ucfirst(date_i18n( 'j F H:i', $ts->getTimeStamp()-(60*60*4))); ?>`

The above php code returns the following date and time:

`July 26  03:30`

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the php code above so that it displays more space between date and time, something like this `July 26     03:30`

This is what I have tried but it didn't work.

`<?php echo ucfirst(date_i18n( 'j F "\t" H:i', $ts->getTimeStamp()-(60*60*4))); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

On a web page you'll need to use `&nbsp;` for extra spaces. So something like:

```
echo ucfirst(date_i18n( 'j F &\n\b\s\p;&\n\b\s\p;&\n\b\s\p; H:i', $ts->getTimeStamp()-(60*60*4)));
```

Comment: &nbsp is not going to work like this, because the date function will replace "n" and "s" from it. OP could however put in a simple "&" (or any other wildcard character), and then str_replace to &nbsp;

Comment: Its returning this on the webpage `July 26 &7b00p; 03:30`

Comment: This works exactly as expected `echo date('j F &\n\b\s\p;&\n\b\s\p;&\n\b\s\p; H:i');`.

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS rule `white-space: pre;` to HTML elements that hold the date.

```css
.spaces-in-date {
   white-space: pre;
}
```

```
echo '<span class="spaces-in-date">' . ucfirst(date_i18n( 'j F     H:i', $ts->getTimeStamp()-(60*60*4))) . '</span>';
```